# find the time difference between two strings of fixed format as "DDD MMM dd hh:mm:ss HKT YYYY"

Tags: bash, date

I grepped from the start time and end time strings from the program log. How can I find the time difference in hour?

```
t1="Tue Feb 21 12:15:00 HKT 2023"
t2="Tue Feb 21 12:45:01 HKT 2023"
```

I looked at other questions. But they have either different formats or directly from date like `date -d 'now + 3 weeks'`

Comment: Will the start and end always be on the same date?

Comment: YES, since they are from the existing program log.

Comment: Does HKT jump forwards/backwards during the year? (It does in some countries, but not in others.)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think HKT means HongKongTime. I never see others.

Comment: What system is this running on (UNIX, Mac, Linux,...?)

Comment: Please do not reply here in the comments. Instead, update your question to include the requested detail. This improves your question and makes it easier for the next person to try and help you

Answer (score 0):

##### Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export TZ='Asia/Hong_Kong'
oldd=$(date -d "Tue Feb 21 12:15:00 HKT 2023" "+%s")
last=$(date -d "Tue Feb 21 12:45:01 HKT 2023" "+%s")
diff=$((last - oldd))
echo "$((diff/3600 )) hours $(( (diff/60)%60 )) minutes $(( diff%60 )) seconds"
```

##### Output

```
0 hours 30 minutes 1 seconds
```